# When to use plural in simple present

Tags: singular-vs-plural, present-simple

Why does ***I watch a movie*** doesn't make sense while ***I watch movies*** makes sense?

While ***I go to church*** makes sense  and ***I go to churches*** doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The singular "I watch a movie" refers to an individual, single, discrete action.

> What do you do to relax after a hard day at work?
>   --I watch a movie. <sub>idiomatic</sub>

The plural "I watch movies" refers to a habitual or regular behavior.

> What is your worst time-wasting vice?
>   -- I watch a movie.  <sub>unidiomatic</sub>
>   -- I watch movies. <sub>idiomatic</sub>

**go** can combine with prepositional phrases with a *singular* object to express the idea of habitual or regular behavior in a specific *role* related to the object of the preposition:

> I go to school.
>
> I go to church.
>
> I go to choir practice.

In these cases, the roles are "to attend *as a student*", "to attend *as a member of the congregation*", "to attend *as a member of the choir*".

When **go** is combined with a prepositional phrase with *plural* object, the meaning is different. **go** then means to make your way to these places as a visitor:

> In your job as building inspector for the Department of Education, what do you do?
>   --I go to schools, and make sure they are safe and that their systems are functioning properly.
>
> When you visit a foreign city as a tourist, what do you see first?
>   --I go to churches because I like architecture that tries to express something spiritual.
>
> As a talent scout for the big music label, what do you do?
>   --I go to choir practices in the hope of discovering the next big star.

Comment: any other verbs like go which requires singular object for habitual behaviour

Comment: @kobe24: **go** + to + {singular object} =  habitual behavior *in a specific role related to the object*, not merely "habitual behavior".